# Rendering Colored Texture, but the result is a gray texture

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders

I am making an object and look like this
[image]

But when i rendered the image, it turns out like this

[image]

This is my render properties

[image]

This is the material properties

[image]

I just want to render the image like the 3d view, can anyone help me please?
I am new at this, and only follow tutorial from youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some light to the scene: https://youtu.be/FdbnzfjoOJU ; your render is just a dark room right now.
If you specifically need the same image as in the viewport, you to go to **View > Viewport Render Image**